# I need field data to be updated in the UI when there is some update in that field from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update document field value in the UI of flutter whenever there is some change in field value in realtime.

I have tried using StreamBuilder but the only output I am getting is 'Instance QuerySnapshot'

```
StreamBuilder(
     stream: db.collection('users').snapshots(),
     initialData: 0,
     builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             return new Text(snapshot.data.DocumentSnapshot,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 12.0));
                        },
                      ),`
```

Expected output is int value of reward field in document uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line `stream: db.collection('users').snapshots(),`
 You are getting the collection, but you expected the document. Refer to the following:

```
StreamBuilder(
 stream: db.collection('users').document(userId).snapshots(), // insert the userId
 initialData: 0,
 builder:(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) { // change to DocumentSnapshot instead of AsyncSnapshot
         return new Text(snapshot.data.documentID, // you can get the documentID hear
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 12.0));
                    },
                  ),`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done one of my project with stream builder and it's working fine. I am putting some code snippet from there please check it out this may helps you.

Code of **StreamBuilder**

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection("students").snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("There is no expense");
          return Expanded(
            child: new ListView(
              children: generateStudentList(snapshot),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

code of **generateStudentList**

```
generateStudentList(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
return snapshot.data.documents
    .map<Widget>(
      (doc) => new ListTile(
        title: new Text(doc["name"]),
        subtitle: new Text(
          doc["age"].toString(),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          width: 100,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _studentNameController.text = doc["name"];
                    _studentAgeController.text = doc["age"].toString();
                    docIdToUpdate = doc.documentID;
                    isUpdate = true;
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.edit,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  deleteStudent(doc);
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
    .toList();
}
```

**You can change fields according your needs.**